# what size tire is compatible with 225 45 17?

Tags: tires, wheels, winter

Looking for winter tires and rims. But can't find much for the 225 45 17 in a 5 x 100 bolt pattern size.

What are some optional other sizes I could put on my 2004 VW Jetta 1.8T?

Comment: @MTA I did re-open the question. I agree with both of you that this is a factual, not an opinion-based question.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the tire inflation sticker inside your fuel filler door.

Compatible tires and rims for this vehicle are listed there as 195/65 R15 on a 6J rim or 205/55 R16 on a 6-1/2J rim.

Model year 1999.5 - 2004 Jetta are all the same with minor cosmetic differences. I have a 2000 Jetta TDI and I use the 195/65 R15 snow tires on all four wheels. They work great.